# Buildozer Unsigned Release APK Saved in Windows Folder, Now Need to Zipalign and Sign It, Windows Environment

Tags: apk, kivy, sign, buildozer, zipalign

My progress thus far:

1. Built an unsigned release APK with Kivy Buildozer VM, command: "buildozer android release".
2. Moved that APK to a Dropbox folder.
3. Installed Android Studio.
4. Read several bits [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-into-apk), [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually), but could not get any of the commands to work from my Windows command prompt.

And that's the whole of it. Several video and text tutorials later, and not one gave a clear-cut, step-by-step process of how to take an already built, unsigned APK and zipalign and sign it. Most assume that devs built their apps in Eclipse, Android Studio, Cordova, etc.

Here's what I've got:

- PyCharm,
- Android Studio,
- Windows Command Prompt,
- Oracle VM VirtualBox, and
- Kivy Buildozer VM.

What else do I need to download and do to get these last few steps done? Can I just stuff my already built APK into Android Studio somewhere and get the rest to work automatically?

Comment: If your problem is that windows doesn't recognize the `zipalign` or `apksigner` command, it may be that you just need to add their location to your `PATH`, or just use the full path to the command. You should be able to find those tools by bringing up your `Android Studio`, then using the menus to get to `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`. The page displayed should show the directory location of your `Android SDK`. Within that directory there should be a `build-tools` directory with sub-directories for each version you have installed. Many will include the `zipalign` and the `apksigner` tools.

Comment: That worked great! I got the rest of the stuff running following these and the documentation notes on the Android dev site.